# Rate-limiting multiple observables created by multiple threads using RxJava

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I'm developing a simple REST application that leverages on RxJava to send requests to a remote server (1). For each incoming request to the REST API a request is sent (using RxJava and RxNetty) to (1). Everything is working fine but now I have a new use case:

In order to not bombard (1) with too many request I need to implement rate limiting. One way to solve this (I assume) would be to add each `Observable` created when sending a request to (1) into another `Observable` (2) that does the actual rate-limiting. (2) will then act more or less like a queue and process the outbound requests as fast as possible (but not faster than the rate limit). Here's some pseudo-like code:

```java
Observable<MyResponse> r1 = createRequestToExternalServer() // In thread 1
Observable<MyResponse> r2 = createRequestToExternalServer() // In thread 2

// Somehow send r1 and r2 to the "rate limiter" observable, (2)

rateLimiterObservable.sample(1 / rate, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

How would I use Rx/RxJava to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a hot timer along with an atomic counter that keeps track the remaining connection for the given duration:

```
int rate = 5;
long interval = 1000;

AtomicInteger remaining = new AtomicInteger(rate);

ConnectableObservable<Long> timer = Observable
        .interval(interval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .doOnNext(e -> remaining.set(rate))
        .publish();

timer.connect();

Observable<Integer> networkCall = Observable.just(1).delay(150, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

Observable<Integer> limitedNetworkCall = Observable
        .defer(() -> {
            if (remaining.getAndDecrement() != 0) {
                return networkCall;
            }
            return Observable.error(new RuntimeException("Rate exceeded"));
        });

Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.flatMap(t -> limitedNetworkCall.onErrorReturn(e -> -1))
.take(20)
.toBlocking()
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Would it be possible to establish backpressure in the request observables instead of throwing? Do I need to write a custom operator for that?